# Variable doesn't update between tests

Tags: python, selenium, testing, class-method

I'm using selenium and I have two tests in my `unittest` class (I'm following a tutorial). I'm using `@classmethod` for `setUpClass`. Each test alone works but both together, like in my code below, doesn't. It appears the variable products in the second test remain the same like in first test, so the lenght is 3 instead of 1. This happens even if I change the name of the variable. So I have an `AssertionError: 1 != 3`. It probabily need time to loading the results of the second search

Why so? What can I do?

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class SearchTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # create a new Firefox session
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page
        cls.driver.get("http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/")
        cls.driver.title

    def test_search_by_category(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        self.search_field.send_keys("phones")
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have product names
        # displayed currently on result page using
        # find_elements_by_xpath method
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath\
            ("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
        print('products', products)
        self.assertEqual(3, len(products))

    def test_search_by_name(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        self.search_field.send_keys("salt shaker")
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have
        # product names displayed
        # currently on result page using
        # find_elements_by_xpath method
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath\
            ("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
        print('products',products)
        self.assertEqual(1, len(products))

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # close the browser window
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: After exciting `submit()` in the second case, are you sure the page has actually refreshed before you get the results? :)

Comment: Probabily no. I'm learning, this is the code the tutorial gives to me, I don't know how to wait for the refresh.

Comment: Why the vote to close like unclear? That's my code, the test_search_by_name doesn't give the correct result. I liked to know why and how to solve. Sorry for my english but the problem looks clear.

Comment: There's no point of arguing with anonymous downvoters/flags in SO; someone took a glimpse of the question, decided it is unclear, and flagged it. His choice; just let it be (I'm speaking from experience :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class SearchTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # create a new Firefox session
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page
        cls.driver.get("http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/")
        cls.driver.title

    def test_search_by_category(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        title = "phones"
        self.search_field.send_keys(title)
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have product names
        # displayed currently on result page using
        # find_elements_by_xpath method
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.title_contains(title)
            )
        finally:
            products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath\
                ("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
        self.assertEqual(3, len(products))

    def test_search_by_name(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        title = "salt shaker"
        self.search_field.send_keys(title)
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have
        # product names displayed
        # currently on result page using
        # find_elements_by_xpath method
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.title_contains(title)
            )
        finally:
            products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath\
                ("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
        self.assertEqual(1, len(products))

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # close the browser window
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Now I wait in both methods until the title of the page change. It works, but what do you think? It is a good way to resolve the problem?

Edit: after the comment I changed again the code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class SearchTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # create a new Firefox session
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page
        cls.driver.get("http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/")
        #cls.driver.title

    def test_search_by_category(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        title = "phones"
        self.search_field.send_keys(title)
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have product names
        # displayed currently on result page using
        # find_elements_by_xpath method
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.title_contains(title)
        )
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath \
            ("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
        self.assertEqual(3, len(products))

    def test_search_by_name(self):
        # get the search textbox
        self.search_field = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        self.search_field.clear()

        # enter search keyword and submit
        title = "salt shaker"
        self.search_field.send_keys(title)
        self.search_field.submit()

        # get all the anchor elements which have
        # product names displayed
        # currently on result page using
        # find_elements_by_xpath method
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.title_contains(title)
        )
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath \
            ("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")
        self.assertEqual(1, len(products))

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # close the browser window
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: As long as it does the job - it is; what's the point of the `try` block, if you are not catching it. Overall, it's better to be w/o a try/catch - if it throws the exception, there was a reason for that.